# Why is Jquery not filling up my ASP.Net Core table with data from my array?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

Im working on a project built on ASP.Net Core MVC.
I have a method ("MostrarDatos()") inside HomeController.cs that reads a Excel file and fills up an array with it. I've checked with console.log and I see the array with the correct information.

Now, when i try to load a table using said array, using Jquery, I cant make it happen.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header"> Load Excel File</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input class="form-control-file" type="file" id="inputExcel" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                         <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="mostrarDatos()">Show Info</button>
                         <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="enviarDatos()">Send info to DB</button>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <table id="tbData" class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>UnixTimestamp</th>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th>ProductName</th>
                                    <th>Gross</th>
                                    <th>Net</th>
                                    <th>Received</th>
                                    <th>Source</th>
                                    <th>Location</th>
                                    <th>ProductID</th>
                                    <th>FromKey</th>
                                    <th>ToKey</th>
                                    <th>FromName</th>
                                    <th>ToName</th>
                                    <th>LuckyChair</th>
                                    <th>MidnightMadness</th>
                                    <th>Gatcha</th>
                                    <th>GiftCard</th>
                                    <th>TransactionID</th>
                                    <th>AffiliateKey</th>
                                    <th>AffiliateName</th>
                                    <th>VendorKey</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Jquery code:

```
<script>
        
    function mostrarDatos(){
        const input = document.getElementById("inputExcel")

        const formData = new FormData()

        formData.append("ArchivoExcel",input.files[0])

        fetch("Home/MostrarDatos", {
            method: "POST",
            body:formData
        })
        .then((response) => {return response.json()})
        .then((dataJson) => {
            
            console.log(dataJson)

            dataJson.forEach((item) => {
                $("#tbData tbody").append(
                    $("<tr>").append(
                        $("<td>").text(item.UnixTimestamp),
                        $("<td>").text(item.Date),
                        $("<td>").text(item.Quantity),
                        $("<td>").text(item.ProductName),
                        $("<td>").text(item.Gross),
                        $("<td>").text(item.Net),
                        $("<td>").text(item.Received),
                        $("<td>").text(item.Source),
                        $("<td>").text(item.Location),
                        $("<td>").text(item.ProductID),
                        $("<td>").text(item.FromKey),
                        $("<td>").text(item.ToKey),
                        $("<td>").text(item.FromName),
                        $("<td>").text(item.ToName),
                        $("<td>").text(item.LuckyChair),
                        $("<td>").text(item.MidnightMadness),
                        $("<td>").text(item.Gatcha),
                        $("<td>").text(item.GiftCard),
                        $("<td>").text(item.TransactionID),
                        $("<td>").text(item.AffiliateKey),
                        $("<td>").text(item.AffiliateName),
                        $("<td>").text(item.VendorKey),
                        $("<td>").text(item.Status)
                        )
                )
            })
        })
}
</script>
```

What Im trying to do is to fill each cell (td) of my #tbData table with its corresponding information on the dataJson array.

[This is the result once I press the "Show Info" button after choosing an Excel file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAwou.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        
    function mostrarDatos(){
        const input = document.getElementById("inputExcel");

        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("ArchivoExcel",input.files[0]);

        //Dentro del fetch va la URL del metodo que creamos en el HomeController.cs
        fetch("Home/MostrarDatos", {
            method: "POST",
            body:formData
        })
        //Espera la respuesta a través de un promise
        .then((response) => {return response.json()})
        //dataJson recive todo el contenido del archivo Excel
        .then((dataJson) => {
            
            console.log(dataJson)

            dataJson.forEach((item) => {
             
            //cada elemento del dataJson se almacena en item
                $("#tbData tbody").append(
                    $("<tr>").append(
                        $("<td>").text(item.unixTimestamp),
                        $("<td>").text(item.date),
                        $("<td>").text(item.quantity),
                        $("<td>").text(item.productName),
                        $("<td>").text(item.gross),
                        $("<td>").text(item.net),
                        $("<td>").text(item.received),
                        $("<td>").text(item.source),
                        $("<td>").text(item.location),
                        $("<td>").text(item.productID),
                        $("<td>").text(item.fromKey),
                        $("<td>").text(item.toKey),
                        $("<td>").text(item.fromName),
                        $("<td>").text(item.toName),
                        $("<td>").text(item.luckyChair),
                        $("<td>").text(item.midnightMadness),
                        $("<td>").text(item.gatcha),
                        $("<td>").text(item.giftCard),
                        $("<td>").text(item.transactionID),
                        $("<td>").text(item.affiliateKey),
                        $("<td>").text(item.affiliateName),
                        $("<td>").text(item.vendorKey),
                        $("<td>").text(item.status)
                        )
                )
            })
        })
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**